# Nx not able to generate component after upgrading to v12

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

After upgrading an *angular nx workspace* to the latest version `12.3.4` and converting the projects from `tslint` to `eslint`, I'm not able to generate components anymore.

When running `nx g c shells/root --project=test-app` for example, an error is thrown saying **'styleext' is not found in schema**. Within the `angular.json` file, the following schematics are defined at the beginning:

```
"schematics": {
    "@nrwl/angular:application": {
      "style": "scss",
      "linter": "eslint",
      "unitTestRunner": "jest",
      "e2eTestRunner": "cypress"
    },
    "@nrwl/angular:library": {
      "style": "scss",
      "linter": "eslint",
      "unitTestRunner": "jest"
    },
    "@nrwl/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss",
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  },
```

Does someone had similar issues after upgrading to `v12`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved: removed the last entry for "@nrwl/angular:component" and it now seems to work!